# Can't drop user from Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, permissions, amazon-redshift

I am trying to drop user form Redshift but it always fails with the same message

> user "XXX" cannot be dropped because the user has a privilege on some
>   object;

Following a google search on it I found out that I need to revoke the user's permissions so I run several revoke queries but I still fail with the same message:

The queries I ran:

```
revoke all on schema YYY from XXX;
revoke usage on schema ZZZ from XXX;
revoke all on database LLL from XXX;
```

Any idea why I still get this failure message ?

Comment: try cascade option to see revoke gets propagated

Comment: @kadalamittai  - Thanks, but it didn't help. I still get the same message

Comment: Answered in https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/143938/drop-user-in-redshift-which-has-privilege-on-some-object

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please deploy [this view from github "v_get_obj_priv_by_user"](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils/blob/master/src/AdminViews/v_get_obj_priv_by_user.sql)

Once done , follow below steps

1. A_user ---User that has to drop

   B_user ---Table ownership of old table need to map to this user.

   If you wish to to change owner of all tables belong to A_user, then

   `select schemaname,tablename from pg_tables where tableowner like 'A_user';`

   For retrieved above tables run

   `alter table schemaname.tablename owner to B_user;`
2. Revoke all on schema where A_user has some privileges

   `select distinct schemaname from admin.v_get_obj_priv_by_user where usename like 'A_user';`

   For retrieved above tables run

   `revoke all on schema XXXX from A_user;`
3. Revoke all on tables where A_user has some privileges

   `select distinct tables from admin.v_get_obj_priv_by_user where usename like 'A_user';`

   For retrieved above tables run

   `revoke all on all tables in schema XXXX from A_user;`
4. Drop user usename;

If there are two database in one cluster, please do this for both databases.

Comment: if you get an error that the admin schema does not exist, just substitute "public" instead of "admin", both in the GitHub proc and in the queries afterwards. This worked a treat, thank you.

Answer (score 6):

The [v_generate_user_grant_revoke_ddl](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils/blob/master/src/AdminViews/v_generate_user_grant_revoke_ddl.sql) admin view allows you to see existing grants and their corresponding revokes.

With this sql:

```sql
SELECT
  ddl
FROM admin.v_generate_user_grant_revoke_ddl
WHERE ddltype = 'revoke'
  AND (grantee = '<USERNAME>' OR grantor = '<USERNAME>')
ORDER BY
  objseq,
  grantseq desc;
```

I was finally able to find all grants and generate the revoke statements.

Comment: This worked for me, but only after I realised I had to revoke the default privileges on the schema **before** I revoked privileges on the schema itself.  So the statement   `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES for user s105486 in schema sor_ccr revoke ALL on tables FROM group dev_sor_ccr_rw;` can only succeed if s105846 has privileges on 'sor_ccr' schema.    In my case, I just granted ALL on the schema, and then revoked ALL once the default privileges were gone.  Only then was I finally able to drop my user.

Comment: Works well, you might have to create the admin schema first with `create schema admin;`.

Answer (score 3):

After trying suggestions from countless posts and threads, awslabs' **[aws-redshift-utils](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils)** provided relief in the form of [admin.v_find_dropuser_objs](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils/blob/master/src/AdminViews/v_find_dropuser_objs.sql) view. It instantly identified the remaining dependencies making it possible to drop the user in question.

Answer (score 2):

already replied [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/244233/160234) on DBA Stack Exchange.

Before you drop a user, you must revoke any privileges that the user has and then transfer ownership of any database objects that the user owns.

1. Download and install the [v_generate_user_grant_revoke_ddl.sql](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils/blob/master/src/AdminViews/v_generate_user_grant_revoke_ddl.sql) script from the AWS Labs GitHub repository. This script creates a view in Amazon Redshift that is useful for the next two steps.
2. Find all privileges granted to the user and then grant those privileges to the user again, as a superuser or another user, as shown in the following example.

   SELECT regexp_replace(ddl,grantor,'')
   FROM admin.v_generate_user_grant_revoke_ddl
   WHERE grantor='' and ddltype='grant' AND
   objtype <>'default acl' order by objseq,grantseq;
3. Find all privileges granted to the user and then revoke those privileges, as shown in the following example.

   SELECT ddl
   FROM admin.v_generate_user_grant_revoke_ddl
   WHERE ddltype='revoke' and (grantee='' OR
   grantor='') order by objseq, grantseq desc;
4. Download and install the [v_find_dropuser_objs.sql](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils/blob/master/src/AdminViews/v_find_dropuser_objs.sql) script from the AWS Labs GitHub repository. This script creates a view in Amazon Redshift that is useful for the next step.
5. Find all objects owned by the user and then transfer ownership to a different user. In the example below,  is the current owner and  is the new owner.
6. Repeat steps 2-5 in each database on the cluster.
7. Drop the user.

   DROP USER

Source: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/redshift-user-cannot-be-dropped/

**EDIT**: In case none of the above works it might be because of a bug in Role Based Access Control (RBAC) system on the Redshift side.

They are planning to apply a permanent fix but in case reach out to AWS Support and they'll be able to apply a workaround on their side (might require a Cluster restart).

Answer (score 1):

Others' answers have been great for untangling this mess of a permissioning system redshift has chosen to employ. However, if, like me, you're a superuser and are getting a permission denied error when trying to alter default privileges in redshift and this is preventing you from dropping a user, be sure to follow @Vince Hill's comment using this sequence:

1. `GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA some_schema TO foobar;`
2. `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR USER foobar IN SCHEMA some_schema REVOKE ALL ON Tables FROM foobar;`
3. `REVOKE ALL ON SCHEMA foobar FROM foobar;`
4. `DROP USER foobar;`

I could not understand for the life of me why I, as a superuser who can delete this entire cluster, was getting a permission denied error when trying step 2 without first doing step 1. Absolutely maddening but thankfully resolved.