# ERROR: user "xxx" cannot be dropped because permission dependency is found

Tags: amazon-redshift

I'm trying to drop a user from a Redshift cluster but receive the following error:

```
drop user "xxx";
ERROR:  user "xxx" cannot be dropped because permission dependency is found
```

I've installed the admin views and revoked all privileges from all tables and schemas. I cannot find any reference to this specific error. It is also not included in this instructional: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/redshift-user-cannot-be-dropped/

```
select ddl from admin.v_generate_user_grant_revoke_ddl where ddltype='revoke' and grantee='xxx' order by objseq, grantseq desc;
 ddl
-----
(0 rows)
```

```
select ddl, grantor, grantee from admin.v_generate_user_grant_revoke_ddl where grantee='xxx' and ddltype='grant' and objtype <>'default acl' order by objseq,grantseq;
 ddl | grantor | grantee
-----+---------+---------
(0 rows)
```

```
select * from pg_user where usename = 'xxx';
  usename   | usesysid | usecreatedb | usesuper | usecatupd |  passwd  | valuntil | useconfig
------------+----------+-------------+----------+-----------+----------+----------+-----------
 xxx |      110 | f           | f        | f         | xxx |          |
(1 row)
```

```
select * from pg_default_acl where defacluser=110;
 defacluser | defaclnamespace | defaclobjtype | defaclacl
------------+-----------------+---------------+-----------
(0 rows)
```

The user in not in any groups either. Any guidances is appreciated.

Comment: This is a new one for me.  Thinking of what could be dependent on a user's permissions I have a couple of ideas.  1) Does this user have any running queries?  2) Does this user have any open connections (sessions)?  3) Is it possible that someone would be operating as user xxx through use of "set session authorization"?

Comment: @BillWeiner Thanks, this is very odd. The user had not run queries for at least the last two weeks, he was not very active. His only access was through a Redshift/Excel ODBC setup. I did not check yesterday, but today there were no active sessions for him. I re-ran the drop user command and got the expected result. There must have been some lingering 'something'. For reference I ran this cmd to see who had active session: `select * from stv_sessions;`. My problem has been resolved by trying again the next day.

Comment: I had a similar issue and this answer was the solution - https://stackoverflow.com/a/44111378/1157208. In short, revoke the user's access to all schema, tables and views they can access in redshift, then you will be able to drop the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user had not run queries for at least the last two weeks, he was not very active. His only access was through a Redshift/Excel ODBC setup. I did not check initially, but a day later there were no active sessions for him. I re-ran the drop user command and got the expected result. There must have been some lingering 'something'. For reference I ran this cmd to see who had active session: `select * from stv_sessions;`. My problem has been resolved by trying again the next day. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STV_SESSIONS.html